# How to apply the sizeof operator to a function pointer and initialize a structure?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

The folowing piec of code generates *error: initializer element is not constant*
at compile time on the line declaring and initializing the user struct variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct user_s {
    char *name;
    void (*(*pred_skip_func))(int);
};

void f1 (int skip) {
    printf("I am f1\n");
}

void f2 (int skip) {
    printf("I am f2\n");
}

void (*(*pred_skip_func))(int);
struct user_s user = {"Manu", pred_skip_func};

int main(void) {

    struct user_s tmp;
    pred_skip_func = malloc(sizeof(tmp.pred_skip_func) * 2);
    pred_skip_func[0] = f1;
    pred_skip_func[1] = f2;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        (*(user.pred_skip_func)[i]) (i);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Moving the initialization in the main function solves the issue, but I want to understand why ? Is there any restriction on structure initialisation ?

More over, as you can see, I created a tmp user_struc variable to get the size of my pointer to function pointers because I was not able to do this in a cleaner way. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question:

"Is there any restriction on structure initialisation ?"

C requires initializers for aggregate types with static storage duration to be constant:

> (C99, 6.7.8p4) "All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals."

Note that in C89 even if the object of the aggregate type had automatic storage duration the intializers had to be constant expressions (this is no longer the case in C99).

Second question:

"More over, as you can see, I created a tmp user_struc variable to get the size of my pointer to function pointers because I was not able to do this in a cleaner way."

You can use your `user` object to compute the size of the member:

```
sizeof (user.pred_skip_func)
```

or use a C99 compound literal if you have not declared any object of the structure type:

```
sizeof (((struct user_s) {0}).pred_skip_func)
```

Comment: In this example the struct user has static storage ? For me not. So I don't understand clearly.

Comment: @ManuelSelva: Variables declared at file scope have *static storage duration*.

Comment: Ok. So declaring a global variable as static is not affecting the "storage duration", but how do we call it ?

Comment: @ManuelSelva adding the `static` specifier to a file scope object declaration only changes the linkage from external to internal.

Comment: @ManuelSelva I updated my answer to answer your second question

Answer (score 2):

As @ouah points out, the problem is that `pred_skip_func` is not a constant value. The compiler complains because `user` has static storage duration, which means its bitwise representation is going to be "baked in" the executable image at link time. In order for this representation to be known to the linker the value for `pred_skip_func` must be a constant.

However, you can specify a "sane default" constant value for the struct member very easily:

```
struct user_s user = {"Manu", 0};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go for `typedefs` for function pointer like below.

```
typedef void (*pfunc_type)(int); 

struct user_s 
{     
    char *name;     
    pfunc_type *pred_skip_func; 
}; 

.....

int main (void)
{
    .....
    pred_skip_func = (pfunc_type *)malloc(sizeof(pfunc_type) * 2); 
    .....
}
```

This will increase the readablity of your program.